# Screen + VIM + alternative colorscheme

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

After exiting vim (7.3.3) in screen (4.00.02), not all of the background of my terminal  returns to its initial color. Instead some of VIMs coloring remains. Can be fixed by using 'clear' or 'reset'. Really annoying.

Something I'm doing wrong?

Relevant parts of my screenrc:

```
shell -${SHELL}
startup_message off
autodetach on
vbell off
multiuser on
altscreen on
term "screen-256color"
```

Tested terminals are rxvt-unicode-256color and gnome-terminal, with bash (all recent).

Merci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put au `VimLeave * !reset` in your .vimrc

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. The problem somehow solved itself over the years, and nowadays I'm using tmux anyway.